# LTC4418 interfacing VALID1 with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply

I want to use [LTC4418](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc4418.pdf) fuctionality of detecting which one of power supplies is on at this moment. Here is my approach to it:

[image]

PS_VALID1 is connected directly to VALID1 of LTC4418 (without any additional components), same for PS_VALID2. BLE_GPIO is a GPIO of 3.3V powered microcontroller.

What I got confused by is the documentation stating:

```
Output Currents
VALID1, VALID2, CAS..............................–2mA/+5mA
```

VALID1 and VALID2 are open-drain outputs, fine, they pull-down to GND or are Hi-Z, but why there is a +5mA output current stated in the docs? Is this circuit correct then?

Comment: Please explain why use transistors? Is it not possible to directly send a signal to the GPIO?

Comment: Good point, actually I could use internal pull up resistors and connect it directly to GPIO without any external components.

Comment: Provided that you know the level of the GPIO is tri-state/low at power up.

Comment: @Huisman I found a comment from manufacturer `when starting up the GPIO pin will be in input mode, but input buffer is disconnected. So basically it's a floating pin with high impedance.` [origin](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/12560/what-is-the-state-of-the-gpio-pins-during-startup-of-the-nrf52832)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the Absolute Maximum Ratings. Those are the values you should not exceed when forcefully sinking or sourcing that pin.
So, don't draw more than 5 mA from the pin, don't source it with more than 2mA.

Without this "Q?A" or "Q?B" transistor, you would be sourcing 3.3V/10k = 0.33 mA, so, the circuit is fine to me.